# How to cut mesh model matching robot template

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, mesh, maya

Given a mesh model (e.g. a box) and a robot template containing volume, aspect ratio and linkage info of sub-parts (basically cuboids), we want to have a cutting algorithm to cut the mesh model into pieces that can match the robot template. We are using Maya for the modelling job.

For example, the mesh model is a 1X1X1 volume=1 box, the robot template has a 1:1:2 volume 0.5 head link with body, and a 1:1:2 volume 0.5 body link with head, then what we need is to cut the box into half.

The matching of volume, aspect ratio and linkage are not strict, reasonable errors can be accepted.

Is there any existing algorithms that can do the job or is there any related topics on this?
Also if you have any idea to solve this problem please enlighten me. Thanks!

**EDIT**

The problem is, given a mesh object, and a robot template, we need to transform it to the robot.

So now my idea is first cut the object into subparts which match the template, then transform the subparts into robot using Inverse Kinematic maybe.

Sample input and output:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the pieces are all topologically boxes, do you need to cut the meshes? Surely it would be easier to use unit cubes and move/scale them to the appropriate sizes...  You'll want them to be separate transforms in any case.

Comment: Also, it seems like a general cube fit algorithm might get more answers on [mathematics.se]

Comment: @theodox Yes, you are right. The problem is trivial if we allow scaling. I didn't state clearly that we can only transform and rotate the subparts.

Comment: @mhlester Thanks for helping me edit :). I agree that another approach is to fit the robot template into the original mesh. I will try to get answers on Mathematics.

Comment: In that case, apply the scaling to the verts.  That won't change the transform scale

Comment: @theodox How about I give you a car model, then I need a robot from the car like the third figure?

Comment: So you're doing convex hull decompsition on a real model? how do you define your pivots?

Comment: @theodox I am not sure if its convex hull decomp. Let me restate the problem. Given a simple mesh model (car, wardrobe), we need to modify the model to make it like a robot. Like this model
http://imgur.com/ob2khVU

and this the final output

http://imgur.com/E3i3ynE

Comment: @theodox The entire procedure should be automatic. The problem I posted above is how to achieve this. http://imgur.com/5LM2fVO
The car model is separated into pieces that satisfy volume, aspect ratio and linkage requirements

Comment: So that's the reason for the cuboidal cuts?   This might be a good reference. the 'Convex' part is overkill but the decomposition seems apposite. http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2009/11/convex-decomposition-library-now.html  The part I don't have a clear idea for is how the skeleton is generated...

Comment: @theodox The cuboidal cuts are meant to be a simplified version of the problem... The skeleton is given and to be matched with the subparts. It's for the 'transformation' purpose later. http://imgur.com/53uCQyp

Each part of the skeleton has properties like volume, aspect ratio and linkage. Once we cut the car model into pieces, e.g. one part with 50% volume 1: 1: 1, then we can match this part to the 'head' of the skeleton.

In the end we could have a similar visual effect like in the Transformer movie.
http://imgur.com/pfFWDhU

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to just  cubes to the correct dimensions by setting the aspect ratio in the cube shape

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def scaled_cube(volume, w, d, h):
    scale_factor = pow( float(volume) / float(h* w * d), 1.0/3)
    return cmds.polyCube(w = w * scale_factor, d = d * scale_factor, h = h * scale_factor)
```

Edit: After the above comments, this will cut out the portion of a mesh contained in a cuboid (defined here as a maya style bounding box (minx, miny, minz, maxx, maxy, maxz - the same thing you'd get from querying the maya bbox):

```
def cut_to_fit_bounds(mesh, bbox):
    '''
    splits an existing mesh
    '''
    cutmesh = cmds.duplicate(mesh)
    minx, miny, minz, maxx, maxy, maxz = bbox
    cmds.select(cutmesh)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (minx, 0, 0), ro = (0, 90,0), df =1, ch=0 )
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (maxx, 0, 0), ro = (0, -90,0), df = 1, ch=0)
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (0, 0, minz), ro = (0, 0,0), df =1, ch=0 )
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (0, 0, maxz), ro = (0, 180,0), df = 1, ch=0)
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (0, miny, 0), ro = (-90, 0,0), df =1,ch=0 )
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.polyCut(pc = (0, maxy, 0), ro = (90, 0,0), df = 1, ch=0)
    cmds.polyCloseBorder(ch=0)
    cmds.select(cutmesh)
```

The previous routine could be used to create appropriately sized volumes - by placing them correctly and grabbing their bounding boxes with cmds.xform(q=True, bb=True) cut volumes could be made. After that you should have a cut up copy of the original, although I'd worry about normal artifacts, sliver polys and material issues which are common when using polyCut.